# Strange closure issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How come in my case I was getting `['undefined1','undefined2']` value for my array? I pushed it in the same scope.

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res) {
    var imageArr = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (req.body["photo" + i]) {
            imageArr.push(req.body.photo + '' + i);
        }
    }

    console.log(imageArr) // working fine here, returning correct values like ['something','something']

    if (req.body.is_update) {
        console.log(imageArr) // working fine here too, returning correct values
    } else {
        console.log(imageArr) // not working fine here, returning undefined1, undefined2.. 
    }
}
```

Is it because of async, possibly?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible: `req.body.photo+''+i`. Maybe you meant `req.body[ "photo"+i]` - same as a line above?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov but how come my previous 2 console it can get the correct value?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov It worked! although I don't know what exactly happening..

Comment: Clearly when `req.body.is_update` is `false` then `req.body.photo` is `undefined`. Check you req.

Comment: @c-smile why that is the case? req.body.is_update is `false` doesn't mean req.body._something_else is `false`, I'm getting other request param with no problem.

Comment: Well it shouldn't have worked with your initial code anyway - check console here - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/sarwdLwb/

Comment: @NikolayErmakov but it my case somehow it worked when I do `req.body.photo+''+i`. Thanks for the fiddle anyway.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer too! Anyway, glad it helped!

Comment: Simple start to understand problem would be to see what the body object looks like. Easy enough to stringify it and log it to console. Then you would get a better answer. Would also help to see what array looks like you created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would turn my comment into a formal answer to this question so it won't hang unanswered.

You need to replace this part of you script `imageArr.push(req.body.photo+''+i);` with `imageArr.push(req.body["photo"+i]);`. Examples of console outputs for both cases can be seen in this [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/sarwdLwb/)